# Showing that the set of matrices $\begin{bmatrix}a & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ is not a subgroup of $ \text{GL}_2(\mathbb R)$

Tags: group-theory

I'm doing the exercise in Algebra (2nd Edition)
Let $G=\text{GL}_2(\mathbb R)$, $H$ is the set of matrices $\begin{bmatrix}a & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, with $a \neq 0$. 
The answer says NO because H does not contain the identity matrix, but I think H contains its own identity = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, and H also fits the property of closure and having inverse  $\begin{bmatrix} a^{-1} & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ . 
This seems to violate the rule that the identity of a subgroup is the same as the group.
But I don't know which part is wrong. 
Thank you very much in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: You forgot the definition of $GL_2(R)$. Any element in it must have nonzero determinant. So "your identity" cannot lie in $H\subseteq GL_2(R)$. In fact, $H$ is **not** a subset of $GL_2(R)$.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much!

Comment: Who is/are the author(s) of the book? Please [edit] accordingly.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @DietrichBurde This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Per site policy, comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg This was not meant as an answer. I only wanted to clarify that the OP has forgotten the definition of $GL_2(R)$. After this "hint" there is nothing more to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The determinant of each matrix in $H$ is zero. Thus $H$ is not a subset of $G$.  Therefore, it cannot be a subgroup of $G$.

---

Alternatively, $I\notin H$. Thus it cannot be the subgroup of $G$.

---

Even if $H$ *were* in $G$, we have the following theorem.

> **Theorem:** Let $G$ be a group. Let $S\subseteq G$. If $f\in S$ is an identity in $S$, then $f=e$.

*Proof:* Let $s\in S$. Then $s\in G$ and

$$\begin{align}
sf=s&\implies (s^{-1}s)f=s^{-1}s\\
&\implies ef=e\\
&\implies f=e. \square
\end{align}$$